# CSS Stop Light with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a stop light animation (rotating flashing light starting with red > yellow > green) and when I hover over any of the lights, it would pause the animation and light up the selected light and show a hover div.

So far everything is working (though I'm sure code could use some optimization) but when I hover over any of the lights, the animation DOES NOT stop immediately. I tried using clearTimeout & clearInternal but nothing is working.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ86B/

Here's my jQuery

```
stopLight();

$('[class^="stopLight"]').mouseenter(function(){
     clearTimeout(window.flashLightTimer);
     clearInterval(window.stopLightInterval);
     $(this).css('background-position-x','-106px');
     $(this).find('span').fadeIn('fast');
}).mouseleave(function() {
     $(this).css('background-position-x','0px');         
     $(this).find('span').hide('fast');
     stopLight();
}); 

function stopLight() {
    window.stopLightInterval = setInterval(function() {
        flashLight('red',1000);     
        flashLight('yellow',2000);
        flashLight('green',3000);
    }, 3000);
};

function flashLight (a, b) {
    window.flashLightTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(".stopLight-"+a).animate({
            'background-position-x': '-106px'
        }, 0, 'linear')
        .delay(1000)
        .animate({
            'background-position-x': '0px'
        }, 0, 'linear')
    }, b);
};
```

Comment: Can you setup a demo on http://jsbin.com or a http://jsfiddle.net ? or a link to a demo page?

Comment: Can you throw some html as well? a jsfiddle will save time here!

Comment: yes, it's really hard to immagine the working jQuery without having the HTML/CSS

Comment: Sorry. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/JZ86B/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reseting the background positions of all of the lights as soon as the mouseenter event is fired? Something like:

```
$(".light div").css('background-position-x','0px');
```

You'll need to tweak things a little more than that, but that would at least "unset" all of the other lights immediately.

Comment: i've tried something similar and it doesn't work. i think the delay() is the culprit. As the light flashes, if i mouseover the light as it's still lit, the next light still lits up then it stops... it's small details but really frustrating :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a big help:

[clearTimeout on Mouse Exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488311/cleartimeout-on-mouse-exit)

here's my final code

```
var timerID = [];

$('[class^="stopLight"]').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('background-position-x', '-106px');
    $(this).find('span').fadeIn('fast');
    for (var i = 0; i < timerID.length; i++) {
        clearTimeout(timerID[i]);
    };
    clearInterval(window.stopLightInterval);    
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('background-position-x', '0px');
    $(this).find('span').hide('fast');
    stopLight();
});

function stopLight() {
    window.stopLightInterval = setInterval(function() {
        flashLight('red', 1000);
        flashLight('yellow', 2000);
        flashLight('green', 3000);
    }, 3000);
};

function flashLight(a, b) {
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".stopLight-" + a).animate({
            'background-position-x': '-106px'
        }, 0, 'linear').delay(1000).animate({
            'background-position-x': '0px'
        }, 0, 'linear')
    }, b);
    timerID.push(timer);
};

stopLight();?
```